# Problem keyboard layout in boot with LUKS

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-layout, luks

I have installed Arch Linux with LUKS on a btrfs file system.

When logging in,
I can't mount my filesystem on `/dev/sda2` because the keyboard is US (I need a French key map).

I try change `/etc/vconsole.conf` to FR and generate locale-gen but the keyboard don't change in next boot.

Comment: Or you could make use of LUKS supporting up to 8 keys, to add your passphrase in US layout as well so it will be accepted either way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your /etc/mkinitcpio.conf needs to look like this:

> HOOKS="... keyboard keymap encrypt..."

You need to load the keymap during boot, which is done by an mkinitcpio hook. Make sure that the **keymap** or **sd-vconsole** hook (depending on whether you use sd-* style hooks) occurs before encrypt/sd-encrypt and regenerate your initrd.

Comment: I added keymap before encrypt on the file /etc/mkinitcpio.conf and I have generate initrd. After adding keymap at startup the keyboard does not work. And now I can't start in my system

Comment: I mount encrypt partitions on archiso And I added on mkinitcpio.conf --> HOOKS: "... keyboard keymap encrypt ..." and regenerate. Thanks for you help

Comment: Great solution, works perfectly. The keymap is sourced from /etc/vconsole.conf, in case anyone is wondering.

Comment: Note, you must regenerate the initrd _after_ configuring `/etc/vconsole.conf`.

Comment: Note that this solution is correct, if [your `/boot` partition isn't also encrypted](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dm-crypt/Specialties#Securing_the_unencrypted_boot_partition). In this case, the solution doesn't work, since GRUB has multiple stages and the above works for stage 2, but not for stage 1! In this case you need to [manually configure a `core.img` using `grub-mkimage`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB/Tips_and_tricks#Manual_configuration_of_core_image_for_early_boot) ([here's a superuser q&a](https://superuser.com/a/1188564/497608)). Took me hours to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 3):

I use luks encryption for home and root files.
If it can help some guys

```
vim /etc/vconsole.conf
```

Add this

```
KEYMAP=fr-latin9
```

and also check this

```
vim /etc/mkinitcpio.conf
```

It MUST be in the good order

```
HOOKS=(base udev autodetect keyboard keymap consolefont modconf block encrypt lvm2 filesystems fsck)
```

Regenerate initrd

```
mkinitcpio -P
```