# How to use Dvorak keyboard layout in GRUB2 LUKS passphrase prompt?

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, keyboard-layout, luks

I've tried to piece together how to do this from various sources. First approach, based on [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/342360/3645) and [2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/System_configuration#mkinitcpio):

```
$ grep ^HOOKS /etc/mkinitcpio.conf
HOOKS="base udev autodetect modconf block lvm2 keyboard keymap encrypt filesystems fsck"
$ grep ^KEYMAP /etc/vconsole.conf
KEYMAP=dvorak
```

Then run `sudo mkinitcpio -p linux` successfully and reboot. Result: the password prompt still uses the US layout.

---

Second approach, based on [3](https://askubuntu.com/a/751260/10371):

1. Install [ckbcomp](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ckbcomp/)
2. Run:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /boot/grub/layout
   sudo grub-kbdcomp -o /boot/grub/layout/us-dvorak-alt-intl.gkb us dvorak-alt-intl
   ```

   (ignored "Unknown keyboard scan code 0x…" warnings)
3. In `/etc/default/grub` set `GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT=at_keyboard`
4. In `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` add:

   ```
   insmod keylayouts
   keymap /boot/grub/layout/us-dvorak-alt-intl.gkb
   ```
5. Run:

   ```
   sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
   sudo grub-install --target=i386-pc /dev/sda
   reboot
   ```

Now I can use Dvorak in the GRUB menu, but not on the LUKS prompt.

---

[Other](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Talk:GRUB#Custom_keyboard_layout) [sources](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/grub-devel/2011-06/msg00008.html) mention a similar approach which I don't think can work because the LUKS prompt shows up before the relevant files can even be read. Finally, one [source](https://superuser.com/a/976106/2259) says this can't be done at all.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174657/30851

Comment: @frostschutz Yeah, that would work. Shame if it's the only way though. Do you want to post it as an answer?

Comment: It's not an answer to your question (you might want Dvorak in grub anyway for the grub shell and whatnot) but it should be a viable workaround for everything else (including livecd/rescue, you just have to make do with US layout in many cases).

Comment: I'd still upvote it - it solves the problem even though it's not the preferred method.

Comment: It is possible, I'd been doing it for some time now. I recently got a hardware-programmable keyboard and needed to change it back to qwerty so the kb itself can be dvorak instead. I found this question since I couldn't remember what I did.. I'm not making an answer since I dont know which of these changes worked, but basically it was either as simple as `localectl set-keymap <YOUR KEYMAP>`, or adding (or in my case, removing) `rd.vconsole.keymap=<YOUR KEYMAP LOCALE` from `/etc/default/grub` @ `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="` along with a `grub2-mkconfig`. It's not impossible both of these are needed..gl