# Enable Belgian keyboard for LUKS-LVM passphrase in OpenSUSE Leap 15.1

Tags: boot, opensuse, keyboard-layout, luks, disk-encryption

I have a new notebook from a German manufacturer with a Belgian keyboard and OpenSUSE Leap 15.1. The notebook was delivered with a temporary passphrase that you can change after completing the OS setup. After finishing the setup (including selecting a Belgian keyboard layout) and rebooting, the passphrase was not accepted until I connected a German keyboard to enter it.

How can I change the system to accept a Belgian keyboard instead of German one? The passphrase contains dashes and underscores, which German keyboards map to other keys than US keyboards, so I assume the system can be set up to accept non-US keyboards.

I have looked at other LUKS passphrase questions, but I still don't know where to start.

- [How to use Dvorak keyboard layout in GRUB2 LUKS passphrase prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/350711/158988) assumes the system has `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` file, which is not present on my system;
- [Problem keyboard layout in boot with LUKS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/342353/158988) also assumes the system has `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` file;
- [unable to open luks encrypted device (wrong password)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/174572/158988): I get stuck when I enter `sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey <device>`: I get the error message `Device <device> doesn't exist or access denied`. (I looked up the `<device>s` using `lsblk -fs`.)

Even though the question is formally about enabling a Belgian keyboard layout, the solution would have wider applicability, since there are many other keyboard layouts other than US querty and German quertz.

PS: I don't have this issue on my old notebook, which came from a different German reseller; it has a French keyboard and is running MX Linux.

---

Update in response to fra-san's comment.

The output of `lsblk -fs` is:

```
 NAME FSTYPE LABEL UUID FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
 system-root            414.6G      2% /
 └─crypt_dev_nvme0n1p3
   └─nvme0n1p3
     └─nvme0n1
 system-swap                           [SWAP]
 └─crypt_dev_nvme0n1p3
   └─nvme0n1p3
     └─nvme0n1
 nvme0n1p1              337.5M      26% /boot
   └─nvme0n1
 nvme0n1p2              510.9M       0% /boot/efi
   └─nvme0n1
```

I had tried `sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey crypt_dev_nvme0n1p3` and `sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey nvme0n1p3`, not knowing I needed to use a full path. (I'm still not sure what the *full* path should be, after trying a few variations begining with `dev/...`.)

Comment: `mkinitcpio` is indeed a tool from Arch Linux, used there and in derivative distributions. About [registering two passphrases](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174657/315749): could you please add the relevant output from `lsblk` and the exact `cryptsetup luksAddKey` command (including the actual device) to your question? `device` should be the full path of the device containing the `crypto_LUKS` volume.

Comment: Is it actually LUKS encryption or regular user login? It's unusual for devices to be delivered with preinstalled LUKS. And if that was the case there are security considerations - regardless which passphrase you set, they might have your master key.

Comment: [System Language](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/startup/single-html/book.opensuse.startup/index.html#cha-yast-lang), [Keyboard Layout](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/startup/single-html/book.opensuse.startup/index.html#sec-yast-hw-keym)

Comment: @frostschutz The device was delivered with a temporary passphrase that could be used only once. After entering that and finishing the openSUSE setup, you are prompted to set a proper passphrase. This is the passphrase you are prompted for when rebooting: "Please enter passphrase for disk primary (crypt_dev_nvme0n1p3").

Comment: @frostschutz I don't have keyboard layout issues once the OS has booted.

Comment: Thank you. What I wanted to point out is that the device you need to run commands against likely is `/dev/nvme0n1p3`. E.g. `sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/nvme0n1p3`. _But_ frostschutz makes a relevant point: adding/removing a LUKS passphrase doesn't change the encryption key, unless the installer took care of (re-)encrypting the volume as part of the setup process. You may want to re-encrypt it to make completely sure.

Comment: @fra-san Regarding the temporary passphrase: I checked whether it still worked and it doesn't (neither with a German nor a Belgian keyboard). I hope this means that the volume was effectively (re-)encrypted.

Comment: @Tsundoku Unfortunately, it is possible to remove a passphrase (e.g. `luksChangeKey` or `luksRemoveKey`) without changing the encryption key. Its secrecy depends on the people who preinstalled the software on your device - i.e. it can not be guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

Such issues with the keyboard layout not meeting my expectations when entering the luks password during boot keep reappearing in Leap15 for me. Therefore here my answer:

Edit `KEYMAP=` in `/etc/vconsole.conf` to match one listed in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`. Example:

```
KEYMAP=us
FONT=eurlatgr.psfu
FONT_MAP=
FONT_UNIMAP=
```

Run `sudo mkinitrd` afterwards to apply the changes.

Based on a [suse forum thread](https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1106673).

Comment: Thanks. The issue somehow resolved itself - I don't know how. On my system, the `KEYMAP` value is `be-latin1`, which does not match exactly any of the entries in `/etc/vconsole.conf` (where I have, of course, a `be` file).