# Which keymapping is Luks using?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, luks

#### Short version

How can I know which keymap is used when I am prompted for my password by LUKS?

#### Long version

I am using three keyboards and their mappings (US-Qwerty, FR-Azerty, and FR-Bepo), and frequently alternates between them. I used [this workaround](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174572/unable-to-open-luks-encrypted-device-wrong-password/174657) to be able to type the same password (that I added [following those advices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1319688/luks-how-can-i-add-more-password-slots-or-remove-change-a-password)) regardless of which mapping is currently active and which keyboard I am using, but don't find it very clean.

Various solutions ([example 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/664665/101324), [example 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/342353/101324)) recommend to edit `/etc/vconsole.conf`, but this file is not present on my installation and I'd rather do without if that's possible. There seems to be a way [by editing initramfs.conf](https://askubuntu.com/a/1027928/411415)  but I'm not sure I understand it correctly, and I would prefer to *first understand which keymap is active now*.

#### Infos

```
uname -a 
Linux XXX 6.1.0-12-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.52-1 (2023-09-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using? What initramfs builder is it using? (Assuming the prompt is for unlocking your root filesystem, that is?)

Comment: Debian stable / I don't know, how can I figure this out / Yes, the prompt is to unlock my root filesystem.

Comment: Debian almost always uses its own "update-initramfs" tool. (Other distros may use dracut, or mkinitcpio, or genkernel, or a few others – they all differ in which config files they'll use; e.g. vconsole.conf usage usually depends on whether the initramfs includes systemd in it.)

Comment: Yes, that's most likely what was run, `update-initramfs`. I was not aware that other distros had other tools for this task, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

LUKS doesn't have keymaps. It doesn't read keyboard input on its own – it's just a generic console program that reads *console* text input, leaving it to the console to map the keys.

> Various solutions (example 1, example 2) recommend to edit /etc/vconsole.conf, but this file is not present on my installation

That's usually normal. Not all configuration files are present on every installation. Indeed a big part of systemd's overall design is that *no* "default" or "template" configs should be present in /etc, with everything static being in /usr/lib instead. (Many other projects have since followed that convention.) So the absence of a config file is not an indicator that the system won't use the file, and should not stop you from creating it if you know that the system *does* use it.

(On the other hand, as in many thing systemd, it *does* have an alternative: the `vconsole.keymap=` kernel command-line option mentioned in the vconsole.conf manual page, which – if your system was using systemd-vconsole for this – you could add to your GRUB configuration.)

That being said, I don't think Debian actually uses systemd-vconsole at all; not even for the main (rootfs) boot. (And the initramfs is a whole separate world of its own, having its own config files and everything. As mentioned in the comments, initramfs building varies greatly between distributions – Debian uses its own "initramfs-tools" to do so, while other distributions may use Dracut, mkinitcpio, Booster, genkernel, and so on.)

So in your case, the Ubuntu instructions for `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` are the most suitable for Debian's initramfs as well.

> I would prefer to first understand which keymap is active now.

Unpacking the initramfs (it is a mini-rootfs in a cpio archive) with `lsinitramfs` or `cpio` or `bsdtar` might reveal what keymap files, if any, are embedded in it. Enabling verbose mode when the initramfs is being built, with `update-initramfs -u -v`, may also reveal it.

But in Debian's case, unfortunately a generic file name seems to be used – it just takes whatever "cached" keymap was present in the main system when the initramfs was built. All it reveals is whether there *is* a keymap in the initramfs, or not.

So if you just built a fresh initramfs, it should be safe to assume that it will either use whatever console keymap has been configured via `/etc/default/keyboard` (if the `KEYMAP=y` option has been enabled in initramfs.conf), or the generic built-in 'us' keymap (if it hasn't been enabled). For example, this shows that the system keymap has been copied into the initramfs:

```
# update-initramfs -u -v
Calling hook keymap
Adding binary /usr/bin/kbd_mode
Adding binary /usr/bin/loadkeys

# lsinitramfs /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-12-amd64 | grep kmap
etc/console-setup/cached_UTF-8_del.kmap

# bsdtar -tf /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-12-amd64 | grep kmap
etc/console-setup/cached_UTF-8_del.kmap
```

Finally, interrupting your initramfs with a kernel option such as `break=premount` should give you a shell at the correct point in time (after loading the keymap but before the LUKS prompt) where you could press keys and see what gets typed.